# Get everything to the left of the second '/' in a date

Tags: vb.net

Like the title says, I am trying to return only the month and day parts of the date field like this '10/12' or '5/5'. I tried using left(date,5), but if the date is '5/5/2018' it will return '5/5/2'. I know substring might be useful but I didn't know how to use it since there is two '/' in the field. Thanks in advance for your responses.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it is really a date in VB, just use the built-in date functions to get the data you need rather than treating it like a string.

Try something like this:

```
Dim dt As New Date(2018, 5, 5)
Dim myVal As String = dt.Month & "/" & dt.Day
```

Answer (score 5):

Parse your date string into a `DateTime` and then use the `ToString` method with your desired format.

```
Sub Main
    Dim dateStr As String = "5/5/2018"
    Dim dt As DateTime
    dt = DateTime.Parse(dateStr)

    Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString("M/d"))
End Sub
```